# create a popupmenu from a SQL

Tags: delphi

How to create a popupmenu from a SQL loop with categories and sub-categories, and at the end of my loop add 2 items to all Level_Depth 3.
please I am a novice would be nice if you can give me a some code how to do.

[You can see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phUkw.png)

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356418/dynamically-create-popup-menu-tree-from-sql-server-table-in-delphi

Comment: https://github.com/coderserdar/Documents/blob/main/Delphi/Embarcadero%20WhitePapers/Object%20Pascal%20Handbook%20(Alexandria%20Version).pdf

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/